# BASH: What is the purpose of using `/` in a list?

Tags: bash, list

**Defining a list:**

```
arr=(2 3 4)
```

**Then changing it like that:**

```
arr=${arr[@]/4}
```

**Printing it:**

`echo ${arr[@]}` => 2 3 3 4

***Why is this the result and what is the purpose of this slash?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${arr[@]/4}` will remove entry with value `4` from original array.

Similarly `${arr[@]/3}` will remove `3`

**Examples:**

```
arr=(2 3 4)

echo ${arr[@]/4}
2 3

echo ${arr[@]/3}
2 4

echo ${arr[@]/2}
3 4

echo ${arr[@]/5}
2 3 4
```

**Explanation of OP's problem:**

```
arr=${arr[@]/4}
```

is equivalent of:

```
arr[0]=${arr[@]/4}
```

which is assigning `2 3` to very first element in array hence making it:

```
2 3 3 4
```

`declare -p` will make it crystal clear:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="2 3" [1]="3" [2]="4")'
```

Not `2 3` at 1st position of this array.

**Correct way** of array assignment is:

```
arr=("${arr[@]/4}")
```

Comment: Correct, but doesn't answer the full question. Like the original poster, I end up with `2 3 3 4` when doing the assignment back to `arr`.

Comment: Correct way to assign values to array is `arr=(${arr[@]/4})` NOT `arr=${arr[@]/4}`

Comment: Thank you -- only 1 cup of coffee so far (not enough)

Comment: lol :) David, I've also added explanation of OP's output `2 3 3 4`

Comment: I see what happened, in my error, with the array already created, `arr=${arr[@]/4}` assigns `"2 3"` as `arr[0]` so after the assignment `echo ${arr[@]/4}` yields `2 3 3`. Try it: `( arr=(2 3 4); arr=${arr[@]/4}; echo ${arr[@]/4} )`  Good Question.